# How can I target a particular branch or layer within the React Checkbox Tree and add a scrollbar and search input field to a specific layer?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tree, react-select

I have a UI tree created with Checkbox Tree ("react-checkbox-tree": "1.5.1") . I want to be able to style any branch or layer within the tree to my taste using css, such as puting a scrollbar in the next layer which is not the root, also I want to place an input field for search. However I don't know how to go about it. Basically, I want to have the flexibility of styling any layer to my taste.

this is how my state look like

```
[
    {
      value: "All",
      label: "All",
      children: [
        {
          value: "consultations",
          label: "Consultations",
          children: [
              {value: "ab", label: "AB"},
              {value: "ac", label: "AC"},
              {value: "ad", label: "AD"}, 
                 children:[
                        {value: "ab", label: "AB"},
                        {value: "ac", label: "AC"},
                        {value: "ad", label: "AD"}, 
                   ],
             },
            ],
        },
        {
          value: "investigation",
          label: "Investigation",
      
        },
        {
          value: "medication",
          label: "Medication",
     
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

I want to be able to add a scrollbar in each of the children array in the three.
this how my Ui look like

```
  <div>
        <CheckboxTree
          nodes={data}
          checked={checked}
          expanded={expanded}
          onCheck={handleCheck}
          onExpand={handleExpand}
          // showNodeIcon={false}
          icons={{
            check: (
              <div>
                <img src={checkMarkIcon} alt="checkMark" />
              </div>
            ),
            uncheck: (
              <div>
                <img src={uncheckedIcon} alt="not checked" />
              </div>
            ),
            halfCheck: (
              <div>
                <img src={indeterminateIcon} alt="indeterminate" />
              </div>
            ),
            expandClose: (
              <div>
                <img
                  src={frontArrowCoverage}
                  className="h-[13px] "
                  alt="indeterminate"
                />
              </div>
            ),
            expandOpen: (
              <div>
                <img
                  src={frontArrowCoverage}
                  className="h-[13px] rotate-[90deg]"
                  alt="indeterminate"
                />
              </div>
            ),
            expandAll: null,
            collapseAll: null,
            parentClose: null,
            parentOpen: null,
            leaf: null,
          }}
        />
      </div>
```

I tried inspecting the element from the browser and using the class names to overide the style but there is so much little I can do. so many elements have the same class names and there seem to be no unique way of identifying each element and styling it.